# Tree, treeBoxObject, getCellAt is not a function?

Tags: javascript, xul

I want to get the value of a selected treecell but i am getting the "tbo.getCellAt is not a function" error, and when i add the `QueryInterface` function i get `Erreur : NS_NOINTERFACE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsISupports.QueryInterface]` this is what i am using :

```
function onTreeClicked(event){
var tree = document.getElementById("treeChildren_links");
var tbo = tree.treeBoxObject;
var row = { }, col = { }, child = { };
//~ tbo.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsITreeBoxObject);
tbo.getCellAt(event.clientX, event.clientY, row, col, child);

var cellText = tree.view.getCellText(row.value, col.value);
alert(cellText);
var redText = getMainWindow().document.getElementById(cellText);
redText.scrollIntoView("true");
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was in the id, i was giving a wrong one (`document.getElementById("Tree_links");`), instead of the giving the parent id (tree) i was using the children id (treechildren).